# Will there be any impact in AWS Athena, if we change the S3 Storage class?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-s3

In our organization, we facing cost issues due to overload of S3 buckets. Too many junk files and archives are stored which are causing this issue.

I recently got an approval to work on Lifecycle policy in AWS S3. Before I start to work on this, I need to clarify that our Athena databases have their storage in one of the S3 buckets.

If we change the storage class, will that impact the Athena database queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the storage class.

If you archive data into Glacier, Athena won't be able to read it and just ignores it. For the other storage classes, e.g. the infrequently accessed ones Athena can still read them, but your costs will increase if they're read at least once per month.

Comment: Thanks Maurice for your valuable comments.
Then if we store the data in Intelligent Tiering, what will be the impact?

Comment: Unless you use the Archive Tiers as described here you should be fine: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-intelligent-tiering-adds-archive-access-tiers/

Comment: Please remember to accept this answer if it helped you to show others this question is resolved.